# Print QR-Code with curent EPC-number from RFID label to Printronix T4000

Tags: printing, label, rfid

we bought a Printronix RFID printer T4304 with these dates:

- FirmwareP301189 V1.21A
- Serial NumberT4K431948007

Our wish is
to produce RFID-Labels with an QR-Code which includes the EPC-number
of the label. The QR-Code shall look like this:

http://qr.mycompany.com/epc/E280689123456789012345

We were hoping to use it with the Software Nicelabel. But Nicelabel
is only able to produce a QR-Code with *only* the EPC-Number but not
with our http://qr.my..../epc/ in front.

I had the idea to save the printjob as file. So I was able to
manipulate the file and send that file as printjob to the Printronix
printer like this:

```
lpr -S 192.168.1.2 -P raw myprintjob.prn
```

I found the document PTX_PRM_PGL_P7_253642C.pdf
which describes how the printer language is working. But I cannot
fulfill my destination.

My myprintjob.prn looks like this:

```
!PTX_SETUP
ENGINE-IMAGE_SHFT_H;0
ENGINE-IMAGE_SHFT_V;0
ENGINE-WIDTH;04146.
PTX_END
~NORMAL
~PIOFF
~DELETE LOGO;*ALL
~PAPER;INTENSITY 8;MEDIA 1;FEED SHIFT 0;CUT 0;PAUSE 0;TYPE 0;LABELS 2;SPEED IPS 6;SLEW IPS 6
~CREATE;FRM;99
SCALE;DOT;300;300
RFRTAG;96;EPC
96;DF511;H
STOP
ISET;0
FONT;FACE 92250
ALPHA
AF511;24;INV;POINT;329;1033;10;10;
STOP
BARCODE
QRCODE;INV;XD9;T2;E0;I1;95;843;
"http://qr.mycompany.com/epc/","EPCCODE"
STOP
END
~EXECUTE;FRM
~REPEAT;1
~AF511;<DF511>

~NORMAL
```

The result is a QRcode which only includes the first part of the string:

"http://qr.mycompany.com/epc/"

but not the "EPCCODE". I am looking for a hint how to do this.

Maybe I could find out the EPC-code via REST or telnet or so and create a special printjob for every single label?

Thanks for your help,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

## Printronix T4000, talk with port 9100 to get info from the printer

### Author

Richard Lippmann, Stadt Zirndorf, EDV

### Documentinformation

- name: talk-with-port9100-to-get-infos-from-printronix-rfid-printer.md
- revision: 2021-12-02 - init

### What I want to achieve

I want to know the RFID-code from the label which is under the print-head.
With this information I am able to build a printjob with Qrcode which includes
the RFID-EPC.

I was not able to find out how to create a print-job with a qr-code.

- I do not want this information in qrcode: ABC1234...567
- But I want this information in qrcode: http://qr.mydomain.com/rfid/epc/ABC1234...567

With that I am able to take a picture of the label and go to a web-application
which helps me further with the device the label is on.

### Documenation, where to find information

- The printer language is described in the document which is easy to google: PTX_PRM_PGL_P7_253642C.pdf

### My environment

Printronix T4000 printer with RFID-unit to read the RFID from the current label.

### How to get info back from my printer

Usually Port 9100 is used to send a printjob to the Printronix-printer. Send job,
don't receive data. But you can switch the printer to be verbose, to send you
back information over the 9100-connection.

### Glossary

- EPC = this is the unique number which is in every RFID-label, just like
  a MAC-address in a network card
- PGL = the printer language. We can send printjobs with it, but also get information
  from the printer about Configuration etc.

### Human connect to the printer via Linux commandline

```sh
ssh me@shell.mydomain.com
export MYPRINTER=192.168.100.3
nc -v $MYPRINTER 9100
```

#### Put verbose mode on

The printer usually only receives information, but does not talk back.
You have to switch on the back-communication.

```
~CONFIG 
SNOOP;STATUS
END
```

#### Put verbose mode off

I you are programming this interface with a programming
language like python, perl, ... it's a good idea to switch
verbose mode off after you did your job.

```
~CONFIG
SNOOP;OFF 
END
```

#### IDENTITY

To see information:

1. put verbose mode on
2. send ~IDENTITY command
3. put verbose mode off

```
~CONFIG 
SNOOP;STATUS
END

~IDENTITY
```

The result is:

```
T43040,V1.21A,12,131072KB
```

#### STATUS

To see information:

1. put verbose mode on
2. send ~IDENTITY command
3. put verbose mode off

```
~CONFIG 
SNOOP;STATUS
END

~STATUS
```

The result is:

```
BUSY;0
PAPER;0
RIBBON;0
PRINT HEAD;0
COUNT;000
GAP;0
HEAD HOT;0
CUT COUNT;000000000
PRINT DIST;000001529
PRCT COMPLETE;000
TOF SYNCED;1
SENSED DIST;00450
END
```

### Read one RFID-EPC-code from current label

These are things mentioned in this command:

- ~CREATE - start creating a new "form" (or subroutine to execute later)
- VERIFY - the name of the subroutine we are creating. Keep it simple,
  less than 15 characters, no special signs (see docu PTX_PRM_PGL_P7_253642C
  page 60 under "CREATE" and page 29 under "Form Name" for exact informations)
- NOMOTION - don't move the label to the next one after executing this job
- DF511 = This is a variable-name, there seem to be a lot of variables in the printer
  which are called by their numbers: DF1, DF2, ... I don't know which one I am
  allowed to use, DF511 seems to work
- 96 = the RFID-EPC on *my* labels are 96 Bits long
- H = Hexnumbers, the code is 96 Bit long, but I would like to see it like this:
  ABC1234...567
- VERIFY - a command to send information to the commandline.
- ~EXECUTE;VERIFY;1 - execute the form 1 time

```
~CONFIG 
SNOOP;STATUS
END

~CREATE;VERIFY;432;NOMOTION 
RFRTAG;96;EPC
96;DF511;H 
STOP
VERIFY;DF511;H;*STARTEPC=*;*=ENDEPC\n*
END 
~EXECUTE;VERIFY;1 
~NORMAL
```

The result is:

```
STARTEPC=E28068940000501EC931EC87=ENDEPC
```

### Read two RFID-EPC-codes

Reads 2 Barcodes and gives back the EPC-codes. With this command the label get
sent (moved) through the printer.

These are things mentioned in this command:

- ~CREATE - start creating a new "form" (or subroutine to execute later)
- VERIFY - the name of the subroutine we are creating. Keep it simple,
  less than 15 characters, no special signs (see docu PTX_PRM_PGL_P7_253642C
  page 60 under "CREATE" and page 29 under "Form Name" for exact informations)
- NOMOTION - don't move the label to the next one after executing this job
- DF511 = This is a variable-name, there seem to be a lot of variables in the printer
  which are called by their numbers: DF1, DF2, ... I don't know which one I am
  allowed to use, DF511 seems to work
- 96 = the RFID-EPC on *my* labels are 96 Bits long
- H = Hexnumbers, the code is 96 Bit long, but I would like to see it like this:
  ABC1234...567
- VERIFY - a command to send information to the commandline.
- ~EXECUTE;VERIFY;1 - execute the form 1 time

```
~CONFIG 
SNOOP;STATUS
END

~CREATE;VERIFY;432
RFRTAG;96;EPC
96;DF511;H 
STOP
VERIFY;DF511;H;*STARTEPC=*;*=ENDEPC\n*
END 
~EXECUTE;VERIFY;2 
~NORMAL
```

The result is:

```
STARTEPC=E28068940000501EC931EC87=ENDEPC
STARTEPC=E28068940000401EC931EC86=ENDEPC
```